# Java Socket - how to catch Exception of BufferedReader.readline()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a Thread (let's say T1) which reads data from socket:

```
public void run() {
  while (running) {
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()) ); 
      String input = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Another Thread (lets say T2) try to finish the program in one of its method. Therefore T2 does the following:

```
T1.running = false;
socket.close();
```

Here is this scenario for which i couldn't find a solution:

- T1 is active and waiting for some input to read i.e. blocking.
- context switching
- T2 is active and sets running to false, closes the socket
- context switching
- because T1 was blocking and T2 closed the socket, T1 throws an Exception. What i want is to catch this SocketException. i can't put a try/catch(SocketException) in T1.run(). So how can i catch it in T1's running-method? If it's not possible to catch it in T1's running, then how can i catch it elsewhere?

PS: "Another question about the Thread Debugging"
Normally when i debug the code step by step, i lose the 'active running line' on a context switch. Let's say i'm in line 20 of T1, context switch happens,  let's assume the program continues from the 30.line of T2, but the debugger does not go/show to the 30.line of T2, instead the 'active running line' vanishes. So i lose the control over the code. I use Eclipse for Java and Visual Studio for C#. So what is the best way to track the code while debugging on a context switch ?

Comment: `SocketException` extends `IOException`. So your `catch` clause should catch `SocketException`.

Comment: Why can't you catch `SocketException` in T1's `run()` method? (It's a subclass of `IOException`, so it will be caught anyway by the existing `catch` clause. If you want to catch it separately, you just have to list it in an earlier `catch` clause.)

Comment: I know that. But somehow, i don't know why, the program doesn't catch it. I mean i put a breakpoint there, but the program never stops in the catch block.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the reader inside the loop?

Comment: @Blesh: actually i do it elsewhere. i just put it there to shorten the code and focus on readline

Answer (score 1):

For your problem assuming you are using a Thread Pool maybe you should make a ThreadFactory that installs a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler on all Threads and then invoke your work with execute() on the ExecutorService instead of submit().

For you problem with debugging maybe you should read 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several other problems so I'll address them all at the same time.

1. You must create the `BufferedReader` *outside* the loop. Otherwise you will lose data in the buffers being discarded each time around the loop.
2. You must test the result of `readLine()` for null. If you get it, you must close the `BufferedReader` and exit the loop.
3. If you get any exception you must also close the `BufferedReader` and exit the loop.

> What i want is to catch this SocketException.

So catch it.

> I can't put a try/catch(SocketException) in T1.run().

You must. No choice. You have to completely rewrite it anyway because of the above items.